# How to post a form to aspx site using python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do a search query using python on this site https://www.ahpra.gov.au/Registration/Registers-of-Practitioners.aspx?m=Search

but am not sure how to correct my code which is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

s = requests.session()
url="https://www.ahpra.gov.au/Registration/Registers-of-Practitioners.aspx?m=Search"
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

formdata = {
   '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value'],
    "__EVENTTARGET": "",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
    "__LASTFOCUS": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT": "2",
    "ctl22$ctl00$ddBoards": "",
    "ctl22$ctl00$ucSearch$txtSearch": "",
    "ctl22$ucSearch$txtSearch": "",
    "ctl22$ddBoards": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtFamilyName": "Mccarthy",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtGivenName": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtRegistrationNumber": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$ddlProfession": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtSuburb": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtPostcode": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$ddlState": "",
    "content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$btnSearch": "Search"
}

headers={"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-AU,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "9282",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=gj3sldhgi23iixqp513jrxx1; __utmc=80649031; __utmz=80649031.1556902975.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atssc=google%3B2; __utma=80649031.910408159.1556902975.1557128827.1557138654.4; __utmt=1; __utmb=80649031.6.10.1557138654; __atuvc=44%7C18%2C8%7C19; __atuvs=5cd00cdf661a62bb004",
    "Host": "www.ahpra.gov.au",
    "Origin": "https://www.ahpra.gov.au",
    "Referer": "https://www.ahpra.gov.au/Registration/Registers-of-Practitioners.aspx?m=Search&content_0$contentcolumnmain_0$txtFamilyName=aa",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"
        }
s.post(url, data=formdata,headers=headers)
```

I get a server error and no results so I guess I'm missing something. Surely there's a way around this?

Comment: There are still some fields from your formdata missing, as in `__VIEWSTATE1`,`__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`,`__EVENTVALIDATION` e.t.c. Did you try including them?

Comment: @SIM Thanks for that I had forgot to include these and now everything works as expected. You can put this as the answer and I 'll mark it as solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is linked with how you are sending `formdata`. Instead of sending it out as a string try sending it as a JSON.

Try replacing this line:

```
s.post(url, data=formdata,headers=headers)
```

with this one:

```
s.post(url, json=formdata,headers=headers)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I've got it working now after following @SIM's comment above. `json=formdata` returns the search form again without results so I used `data=formdata` instead.